# OKTA authentication for ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, okta, okta-api

I have to develop an ASP.NET MVC website. For authentication, we have decided to use OKTA as the authentication provider. We do not want to use Okta API, but we would like to use SAML implementation. Are there any articles/guidelines available on this? I also would like to know how can we extend this to a WCF service. All of these will be hosted in Azure.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the SAML libraries that I suggest using to add SAML to an ASP.NET MVC website:

For [.NET Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history) 4.5 or above use [Kentor Authentication Services](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices#kentor-authentication-services).

For .NET Framework 4 or below use [ComponentSpace SAML 2.0](http://www.componentspace.com/SAMLv20.aspx). (Paid software, licenses start at $299)

High level guidance on adding SAML support to an existing application is available here: http://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/saml_guidance.html

Comment: I think these links show direct interaction with the Service p and IP.